# Because package_name requires SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.0.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my project I am using flutter package [new_version_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version_plus) but when I use pub get it gives an error as follows:

Because package_name requires SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because package_name requires SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

I made the changes as per required SDK version but still I got the same error.

Comment: Can you share the SDK Version which is installed on your device?

Comment: Downgrade your package version and run flutter pub get OR upgrade the flutter version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade flutter using `flutter upgrade` command and then flutter will use latest version of Dart SDK.

Update 'SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.0.0' like this in `pubspec.yaml` file.

pls check new version package official doc example : https://github.com/CodesFirst/new_version_plus/blob/master/example/pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You should not update the dart version of this project, open `pubspec.yaml` file and update

> environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" or Whatever your `sdk version`

to

> environment: sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"